# Struggling with participle phrases - adjectival vs adverbial

Tags: participles, australian-english, nonfinite-verbs

I'm struggling to identify when a participle phrase is adjectival vs. adverbial.

For example: **Turning into the parking lot**, the girl could see that lines were already forming.

^ "**Turning into the parking lot** = Adverbial present-participle phrase" --> but is it modifying the girl, or her seeing that lines were already forming? Isn't the girl the one turning into the parking lot? So isn't it adjectival, because it's describing the girl?

Another example that confuses me:

*It came to pass that, **settling** permanently in Paris he, too, forgot the child, especially when the Revolution of February broke out, **making an impression** on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life.*

"There appears to be two participle phrases in this sentence:

SETTLING: adverbial present participle

MAKING AN IMPRESSION: adverbial present participle"

^ I have absolutely no clue how to identify whether these are adjectival or adverbial (adverbial in both cases, according to textbook). Also how do we know which words are actually included in the participle phrase? For example, I thought the first participle phrase would be "settling permanently in Paris" and not "settling"; I also thought the second participle phrase would be "making an impression on his mind that" and not "making an impression".

Comment: I'm actually not sure the textbook is right about your first example. I'm fairly confident that "Turning into the parking lot" is adjectival, modifying "she."

Comment: Dee: Which textbook are you citing?

Comment: @DanielAsimov I am citing 'Analyzing Grammar in Context' (website textbook)

Answer (score 4):

> (1) ***Turning into the parking lot**, the girl could see that lines were already forming.* 
> (2) *It came to pass that, **settling permanently in Paris**, he too forgot the child, especially when the Revolution of February broke out, **making an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life**.* (I've changed the punctuation a bit.)

Participle phrases are in bold. As you notice, we have one in (1) and two in (2).

(1) means (1'):

> (1') ***When she turned into the parking lot**, the girl could see that lines were already forming.*

Just as ***When she turned into the parking lot*** cannot be said to modify *the girl* in (1'), ***Turning into the parking lot*** cannot be said to modify *the girl* in (1). Both simply add supplementary information to the main clause. If you want to call that "adverbial", fine. But I think "supplementary" is a better term.

Similarly, (2) means (2'):

> (2') *It came to pass that, **when he settled permanently in Paris**, he too forgot the child, especially when the Revolution of February broke out, **which made an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life**.*

As in (1'), both the boldfaced portions add supplementary information to the *that*-clause. Here, the first portion in bold *is* an adverbial but the second portion is not an adverbial but a supplementary relative clause that adds supplementary information to the clause *the Revolution of February broke out*. Therefore, both participle phrases in (2) are also supplementary.

All in all, I believe it to be more accurate and consistent to treat these "participle phrases" (or participle clauses) as supplements than as either adverbials or adjectivals.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. In (1), the *adjectival* phrase "Turning into the parking lot" modifies "girl" in the first example. In (2) the *adjectival* phrase "settling permanently in Paris" modifies "he"; and "making an impression on his mind that he remembered all his life" is an *adjectival* phrase that modifies "the Revolution of February".

Comment: @DanielAsimov Thanks for the feedback. Let me ask you a question, then. If, for example, "Turning into the parking lot" modifies "girl" in the first example, as you claim, why (1)'s equal in meaning to (1'), not to "the girl who turned into the parking lot could see that lines were already forming"?

Comment: Making use of different sentences whose apparent meaning seems the same as the sentence in question is not a reliable way to analyze grammatical structure.

Comment: @DanielAsimov Then, what's the reliable way? Your way is simply alleging that "Turning into the parking lot" modifies "girl", when it apparently doesn't.

Comment: It helps a lot to study English grammar.

Comment: @DanielAsimov Conflating "the girl turning into the parking lot could..." with "Turning into the parking lot, the girl could..." would only confuse learners of English grammar, rather than help them.

Answer (score 2):

1. 

> "**Turning into the parking lot** = Adverbial present-participle phrase" --> but is it modifying the girl, or her seeing that lines were already forming? Isn't the girl the one turning into the parking lot? So isn't it adjectival, because it's describing the girl?

Modification is a relative concept that applies to the domain of grammar only.
Let's consider a situation in which a girl (call her Ruth), can be seen turning into a parking lot.

You can say this.

- The girl is turning into the parking lot.

The action of turning in this sentence is not considered to be a modifier of the noun "girl".

Someone else might want to speak about the same situation but as seen from the background of a  more complex situation that the speaker responsible for the preceding phrase did not consider;  there are in fact other girls on the road, and they are not all turning into the parking lot. Then that person might say this.

- The girl turning into the parking lot is Ruth.

In this new sentence the action of turning *is* considered to be a modifier of the noun "girl"; yet, this is the  girl mentioned in the first sentence, doing the same thing, at the same time;  she and her action are only considered from different points of view. One can see then that modification is not an intrinsic attribute of the referent but instead an  attribute of the noun relative to the circumstances that the sentence is made to situate the referent into.

From the instant that this is accepted, there is no case for relying on the actions per se, and only the syntax (principally) and also sometimes the semantics will tell whether modification is involved or not; this is so because the syntax is chosen so as to match the circumstances, the reference frame for the action, so to speak.

(*no reference for the above, personal deductions from user LPH*)

2.

> Turning into the parking lot, the girl could see that lines were already forming.

The syntax, here, is rather clear. The head of the phrase is "girl" and the determiner is "the"; if there was premodification by means of an *-ing* participle this participle would have to be found after the determiner; moreover, *-ing* participles in premodification cannot have a prepositional complement;  premodification by means of an adverb is posssible, though. Also, as an essential feature of premodification by *-ing* participles, the action that the verbal form embodies must show some degree of permanence or be characteristic.

> (**CoGEL § 17.98**) The possibility of modification by a present participle depends on the potentiality of the participle to indicate a permanent or characteristic feature.

- The often missing component was costly. (*permanent feature*)
- <s>The turning girl could see the lines.</s> (*Turning into the parking lot can't take too long.*)
- <s>The crying in the parking lot girl could see the lines.</s> (*No prepositional complement allowed*)
- The girl  crying in the parking lot could see the lines. (*correct*)
- The crying girl could see the lines. (*also correct but less informative*)

3. 

> It came to pass that, **settling permanently in Paris** he, too, forgot the child, especially when the Revolution of February broke out, **making an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life**.

The first *-ing* participle is not near a noun; the pronoun "he" is the closest part of speech, but the possibility of premodification of personal pronouns is inexistent, so we are dealing with a nonfinite clause. The second *- ing* participle has an object, and so it cannot have a function of premodification; anyway, there is nothing to premodify. Also, there is obviously no noun that can be postmodified.

> (**CoGEL § 5.1**)  Such pronouns can 'deputize'
> for noun phrases and hence cannot normally occur with determiners such as
> the definite article, premodification, or (normally) postmodification:
>
> - *the blonde she      ?she in blue jeans

4. 

> For example, I thought the first participle phrase would be "settling permanently in Paris" and not "settling"; I also thought the second participle phrase would be "making an impression on his mind that" and not "making an impression".

This is correct as far as the first phrase goes. Syntax and semantics are the  key. "Permanently" (rather redundant) and "in Paris" (place) are usual adverbials following "settle", and as there is no comma after "settle" there is no doubt that these two adverbials belong to the phrase. The second phrase reaches to the end of the sentence: "making an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life".

5.

> Turning into the parking lot, the girl could see that lines were already forming.

*When turning into the parking lot, the girl…*. The clause is a subjectless supplementive clause with the function of time adverbial (time adjunct, because it denotes circumstances of the situation in the matrix clause). (There is no difficulty distinguishing those because "time disjunct" is meaningless, such disjuncts do not exist except as the restricted category of frequency disjuncts (*generally speaking, normally speaking*). user LPH)

> (**CoGEL § 15.20**) **Adjuncts and disjuncts**
> Adjuncts and disjuncts tend to differ semantically in that adjuncts denote
> circumstances of the situation in the matrix clause, whereas disjuncts
> comment on the style or form of what is said in the matrix clause (style
> disjuncts) or on its content (content or attitudinal disjuncts). The primary
> difference is that they differ syntactically in that disjuncts are peripheral to the clause to which they are attached.

6. 

> It came to pass that, **settling permanently in Paris** he, too, forgot the child, especially when the Revolution of February broke out, making an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life.

*… after settling …*. The clause is a subjectless supplementive clause with the function of time adverbial (time adjunct, because it denotes circumstances of the situation in the matrix clause ("he, too, forgot the child")).

7.

> It came to pass that, settling permanently in Paris he, too, forgot the child, especially when the Revolution of February broke out, **making an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life**.

For this last clause, although it is easy to parse, the general case that it exemplifies is a source of problems.

> (**CoGEL § 15.61**) **Subjectless supplementive clauses**
> The formal characteristics of subjectless supplementive clauses are:
> (a) They are participle or verbless clauses.
> (b) Their most typical positions in the superordinate clause are initial, final, and immediately after their antecedent, ie the noun phrase in the
> superordinate clause which is identical with their implied subject.
> The position immediately after the antecedent poses the most difficulties
> for analysis. When subjectless supplementive clauses occur in that position,
> they may be indistinguishable from postmodifying participle clauses or (in
> the case of verbless clauses) from noun phrases in apposition. Thus the two
> constructions may merge in that it is impossible (and semantically
> unimportant) to decide whether the participle clause in [1] is to be regarded
> as functionally equivalent to the nonrestrictive relative clause in [1a]:
>
> - This substance, discovered almost by accident, has revolutionized
>   medicine. [1]
> - This substance, which was discovered almost by accident, has
>   revolutionized medicine. [1a]
>
> Alternatively, it may be equivalent to a subjectless supplementive clause:
>
> - Discovered almost by accident, this substance has revolutionized
>   medicine.

> (**CoGEL § 15.62**) **Supplementive clauses in final position**
> In spite of their resemblance to nonrestrictive relative clauses, supplementive
> clauses need not be separated from their matrix clause intonationally when
> they occur in final position. The following are therefore alternative renderings of the same sentence, differing only in that [1] has two focuses of information, whereas [2] has only one:
>
> - The manager apPRÒACHED us, SMÌling. [1]
> - The manager approached us SMÌling. [2]
>
> One result of the alternative shown in [2] is the possible neutralization of the formal difference between nonfinite clauses functioning as supplementive
> clauses and those functioning as complementation of the verb. Thus [3] is
> ambiguous :
>
> - I saw Pam going home.  [3]
>
> On one interpretation (that of the supplementive clause), *I* is the implied
> subject of going home, whereas on the other (that of verb complementation),
> *Pam* is the overt subject.
> Another result of the lack of intonation is illustrated in [4] and [5]. When
> the *-ing* participle immediately follows certain finite verbs with existential
> meaning, the latter seem close to being aspectual catenatives […]:
>
> - Frank sat reading the newspaper. [4]
> - Edith came running towards us. [5]
>
> Further, a sentence such as [6] is ambiguous in more than one way:
>
> - I caught the boy waiting for my daughter. [6]
>
> In addition to the two possible structures of [3], this may be interpreted as
> having a third structure, in which the nonfinite clause is a postmodifying
> clause :
>
> - 'I caught the boy while I was waiting for my daughter.' [supplementive
>   clause]
> - 'I caught the boy in the act of waiting for my daughter.' [verb
>   complementation]
> - 'I caught the boy who was waiting for my daughter.' [postmodification]

It can be seen from the examples in this preceding paragraph that semantics is sometimes all that can be depended on as the last resort.

"**making an impression … life**" is a subjectless supplementive *-ing* clause functioning as a *sentence adverbial*. It is a sentence adverbial because it relates to the remainder of the clause ("the Revolution of February broke out") rather than to the verb only ("broke out").This adjunct is of the type called "*contingency adjunct*"; the particular kind of contingency can be called "result" or "consequence".

> (**CoGEL § 8.36**) **Sentence adjuncts**
> The most obvious way in which sentence adjuncts mark themselves off from
> predication adjuncts is by their relative freedom to occur at I [initial position] as well as E [end]. In this way they demonstrate what we can intuitively feel: that they relate to the sentence as a whole rather than solely or predominantly to the V  and post-V elements. Thus *on the cheek* and *on the platform* both possess the adjunct characteristics […]:
>
> - She kissed her mother on the cheek. [1]
> - She kissed her mother on the platform. [2]

- It came to pass that, settling permanently in Paris he, too, forgot the child, especially when, **making an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life**, the Revolution of February broke out. (*Changing the place of the adverbial (of the particular sort called "sentence adjunct") from E to I changes nothing to the meaning. The style, however, might not be the preferred one.*)

The claim that the clause is a sentence adjunct seems inescapable as it can be replaced by a sentential relative clause without change in the meaning.

It came to pass that, settling permanently in Paris he, too, forgot the child, especially when the Revolution of February broke out, **which made  an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life**.

Answer (score 1):

> For example: Turning into the parking lot, the girl could see that lines were already forming.
>
> "Turning into the parking lot = Adverbial present-participle phrase" --> but is it modifying the girl, or her seeing that lines were already forming? Isn't the girl the one turning into the parking lot? So isn't it adjectival, because it's describing the girl?

"Turning into the parking lot" is an adverbial phrase and a free modifier.

Free modifiers do not modify a particular word as bound modifiers do.

Most commonly, the adverbial free modifier will be a single adverb:

"Fortunately, the door was open" which, when we look  at it turns out to be "The door was open, which was fortunate" in which the event/state of the main clause was the thing that was fortunate.

"Turning into the parking lot" modifies the main clause "the girl could see that lines were already forming."

Thus we have

Turning into the parking lot, the girl could see that lines were already forming. ->

The girl could see that lines were already forming *as she was turning into the parking lot*.

Answer (score 0):

In traditional grammar terms, you have two reduced adverb clauses and a reduced relative (adjective) clause.

These two are [**reduced adverb clauses**](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-adverbial-clause-1691902):

> *As she turned into the parking lot, the girl could see that lines were already forming.* →
> ***Turning into the parking lot**, the girl could see that lines were already forming.*
>
> *. . . as he settled permanently in Paris he, too, forgot the child . . .*  →
> *. . . **settling permanently in Paris** he, too, forgot the child . . .*

This one is a **reduced relative (adjective) clause**. When it modifies a whole proposition, not just a noun, it is sometimes called a connective or [sentence relative clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/relative-clause-grammar-1692042#mntl-sc-block_1-0-19):

> *. . . the Revolution of February broke out, which made an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his
> life.*  →
> *. . . the Revolution of February broke out, **making an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life**.*

Once theses clauses are reduced, they can be called participle phrases (grammar terms vary). The phrase is the participle plus everything else that’s along for the ride:

> *turning into the parking lot*
> *settling permanently in Paris*
> *which made an impression on his mind that he remembered all the rest of his life*

Answer (score -1):

According to the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar, 'adjectival' and 'adverbial' are not comparable terms.

> Note that the terms adjectival and *adverbial are not entirely comparable. Adverbial can denote one of the main *elements (1) in clause
> structure (the others being *subject, *verb, *object, and
> *complement); it is then a function label. Adjectivals operate at a lower level, often as part of a noun phrase (which itself may function
> as subject or object). An adjectival may in some instances be the sole
> realization of a complement (e.g. You look **hungry**), but the adjectival
> as such is not a functional element in clause structure.

If you are looking at participials as elements functioning in clause structure, they will never be 'adjectivals'; instead, they will be subjects, complements, or 'adverbials'. The definition of an 'adjectival' is vague at best, from the same source:

> Loosely, (a *word, *phrase, or *clause) behaving like an *adjective
> (including single-word adjectives)

To use this in reference to a function in clause structure would conflate form and function, a grave mistake.